# download a file from url and save it to file folder on a server in java

Tags: java, url

how to download a file from a url to a file folder located on a server using java.

For now  have written a code which downloads a file to a local folder on my C: but I have to save the file to a server

Comment: Where is that code ? It seems you are writing that file to response object. You need to write that to localfile system. Look in that direction.

Comment: run the code on server

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. But I could just think of 3 options which I have tried in different scenarios, assuming that your operating system is Windows.

1) If its a Windows server you should have a shared folder with write access 
2) If its a UNIX server your code should be running on that server, so that you can write to a relative folder on that server with write access 
3) If its a FTP server, you can FTP upload to that server.